Dynamic Python SQL Statement with column names from a value of a Database
I have a table with names, year and a score/count:
 ("Andi", 2020, 40),
 ("Andi", 2021, 60),
 ("Andi", 2022, 55),
 ("Andi", 2023, 55),
 ("Alex", 2020, 14),
 ("Alex", 2021, 1),
 ("Alex", 2022, 13),
 ("Alex", 2023, 13),
 ...

I try to zip that into an Excel file with writefile() etc.
And it should look like this



NAME
2020
2021
2022
2023
TOTAL




Andi
40
60
55
55
210


Alex
14
1
13
13
41



And ofc next year they will be new records added:
("Andi",2024,49), ("Alex",2024,10),...
So the sqlstament should be also add that when I recreate the Excel file again next year.
I have found this:
How to select Column value as Column name with conditions in SQL table
which is hardcoded and works how I would want it but I dont want to change it every year.
My Database also starts at 2016, so that would be a very long statment.
I tried to make for loops for select, from, on,... but I think there could be an easier way?
Any ideas how I can achieve that?
Thank you

Can you share your current attempt(s) as a [mre], showing how you’re firstly pulling the data, transforming it, then writing it in a way you feel isn’t going to meet your requirements into the coming years?

I only changed the SQL Fiddle example of the link I posted to change from gender/age to 2020 and 2021. I also started to write the statment in python, but didnt finish it, tho to too much effort than it probably was necessary.

You could use Python to get the current/previous year and pass it the the sql query. Why does the link in your question link ti mysql, but you tagged the question by sqlite, which database do you use ?

hm I guess I could just use one sql statment per year and fill up a list and write it into the excel. I thought maybe it would be faster if I have a SQL statment that brings back the whole query at once. I use sqlite in my python. The statements are the same, arent they?

You can use a SQL query like below to pivot the columns names as year.
SELECT name, 
MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2020 THEN score END) AS '2020', 
MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2021 THEN score END) AS '2021',
 MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2022 THEN score END) AS '2022',
 MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2023 THEN score END) AS '2023',
 MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2024 THEN score END) AS '2024', 
 COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2020 THEN score END), 0)+COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2021 THEN score END), 0)+COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2022 THEN score END), 0)+COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2023 THEN score END), 0)+COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2024 THEN score END), 0) AS total
 FROM scores
 GROUP BY name
 ORDER BY name;

This can be dynamically generated as when new years get added in.
# Get all the years
cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT year FROM scores ORDER BY year")
years = cursor.fetchall()

# Generate the pivot columns as years
columns = []
for year in years:
    columns.append(f"MAX(CASE WHEN year = {year[0]} THEN score END) AS '{year[0]}'")

columns_str = ", ".join(columns)



sql = f"""
SELECT name, {columns_str}, 
       {"+".join([f"COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN year = {year[0]} THEN score END), 0)" for year in years])} AS total
FROM scores
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name;
"""


cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(result, columns=['name'] + [str(year[0]) for year in years] + ['total'])
print(df)

Output
   name  2020  2021  2022  2023  2024  total
0  Alex    14     1    13    13    10     51
1  Andi    40    60    55    55    49    259

